# My select list does not show refreshed data after ajax call

Tags: html, ajax, refresh, display

I am trying to implement a select list script with pictures while the options are retrieved via an ajax call. The HTML is refreshed, but the new data are not displayed in the updated HTML-select-list. Please point to a solution.

I have seen lots of similar questions here and elsewhere on the internet, but I get lost on the variation of problems. Most solutions refer to the data not being refreshed, but that is not my problem.

I have the picturelist script working OK with plain data (see below).
I have a page using the AJAX-calls, updating 4 select lists. The first needs to show the picturelist. The data are updated in all 4 lists (proven by selecting SHOW HTML SOURCE from Firefox after selecting the section.

I know my way of updating the data is probably using unneccessary hidden objects, but for now that is not what I am trying to solve (unless it is the cause of my problem). The background is that my solution will be implemented in an existing website, for which I am not able to rebuild the whole page.

My picturelist script (found on the internet, not my coding):

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var li = $("<li>"),
        wrapper = $("<div>", {
          text: item.label
        });
      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }
      $("<span>", {
          style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
          "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
        })
        .appendTo(wrapper);
      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
    }
  });

  $("#input_2")
    .iconselectmenu()
    .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");
});
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

/* select with CSS avatar icons */
option.avatar {
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.avatar .ui-icon {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<title>Test color picking with images in select list</title>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="do_next.php">
  <label for="color_id">Select a color:</label>
  <select name="color_id" id="input_2">
    <option value="1" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/groen_16x16.png')">groen</option>
    <option value="2" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/rood_16x16.png')">rood</option>
    <option value="3" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/geel_16x16.png')">geel</option>
    <option value="4" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/blauw_16x16.png')">blauw</option>
    <option value="5" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/zwart_rood_16x16.png')">zwart/rood</option>
    <option value="6" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/rood_zwart_16x16.png')">rood/zwart</option>
    <option value="7" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/babyroze_16x16.png')">babyroze</option>

    <option value="8" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/groen_16x16.png')">groen</option>
    <option value="9" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url('images/sample/zwart_16x16.png')">Zwart</option>
  </select>
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

My HTML-page:

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var li = $("<li>"),
        wrapper = $("<div>", {
          text: item.label
        });

      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }

      $("<span>", {
          style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
          "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
        })
        .appendTo(wrapper);

      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
    }
  });

  $("#input_2")
    .iconselectmenu()
    .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");
});


function vul_waarde() {
  $product1 = document.getElementById("Product_1").getAttribute("waarde");

  $waarde1 = document.getElementById("input_2").value;
  document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_1").waarde = $waarde1;
  document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_1").innerHTML = $waarde1;

  $waarde2 = document.getElementById("input_3").value;
  document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_2").waarde = $waarde2;
  document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_2").innerHTML = $waarde2;

  $waarde3 = document.getElementById("input_4").value;
  document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_3").waarde = $waarde3;
  document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_3").innerHTML = $waarde3;

  $waarde4 = document.getElementById("input_5").value;
  document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_4").waarde = $waarde4;
  document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_4").innerHTML = $waarde4;

  refresh_keuzelijst1($product1, $waarde1, $waarde2, $waarde3, $waarde4);
  refresh_keuzelijst2($product1, $waarde1, $waarde2, $waarde3, $waarde4);
  refresh_keuzelijst3($product1, $waarde1, $waarde2, $waarde3, $waarde4);
  refresh_keuzelijst4($product1, $waarde1, $waarde2, $waarde3, $waarde4);

}

function refresh_keuzelijst1(p1, w1, w2, w3, w4) {

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var keuzelijst = "";
  var positie = 0;
  var geselecteerde_waarde = "";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("input_2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_2").value
      document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_1").setAttribute("waarde", document.getElementById("input_2").value);
    }
  };

  var aanroep = "attribute_combinations_ajax_server.php?l1=1&p1=" + p1 + "&w1=" + w1 + "&w2=" + w2 + "&w3=" + w3 + "&w4=" + w4 + "&view=all";
  xmlhttp.open("GET", aanroep, true);

  xmlhttp.send();

};

function refresh_keuzelijst2(p1, w1, w2, w3, w4) {

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("input_3").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_3").value
      document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_2").setAttribute("waarde", document.getElementById("input_3").value);
    }
  };

  var aanroep = "attribute_combinations_ajax_server.php?l1=2&p1=" + p1 + "&w1=" + w1 + "&w2=" + w2 + "&w3=" + w3 + "&w4=" + w4 + "&view=all";
  xmlhttp.open("GET", aanroep, true);

  xmlhttp.send();

};

function refresh_keuzelijst3(p1, w1, w2, w3, w4) {

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("input_4").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_4").value
      document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_3").setAttribute("waarde", document.getElementById("input_4").value);
    }
  };

  var aanroep = "attribute_combinations_ajax_server.php?l1=3&p1=" + p1 + "&w1=" + w1 + "&w2=" + w2 + "&w3=" + w3 + "&w4=" + w4 + "&view=all";
  xmlhttp.open("GET", aanroep, true);

  xmlhttp.send();

};

function refresh_keuzelijst4(p1, w1, w2, w3, w4) {

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("input_5").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_4").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_5").value
      document.getElementById("Waarde_Lijst_4").setAttribute("waarde", document.getElementById("input_5").value);
    }
  };

  var aanroep = "attribute_combinations_ajax_server.php?l1=4&p1=" + p1 + "&w1=" + w1 + "&w2=" + w2 + "&w3=" + w3 + "&w4=" + w4 + "&view=all";
  xmlhttp.open("GET", aanroep, true);

  xmlhttp.send();

};
```

```css
<style>h2 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
}


/* select with CSS avatar icons */

option.avatar {
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.avatar .ui-icon {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<title>Test color picking with images in select list</title>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<!-- // JL 1-2-2021 BEGIN -->
<p hidden="hidden">Geselecteerd product: <span id="Product_1" waarde=""></span></p>
<p hidden="hidden">Product: <span id="products_id" waarde=""></span></p>
<p hidden="hidden">Geselecteerde waarden (1): <span id="Waarde_Lijst_1" waarde="" option_id="2"></span></p>
<p hidden="hidden">Geselecteerde waarden (2): <span id="Waarde_Lijst_2" waarde="" option_id="3"></span></p>
<p hidden="hidden">Geselecteerde waarden (3): <span id="Waarde_Lijst_3" waarde="" option_id="4"></span></p>
<p hidden="hidden">Geselecteerde waarden (4): <span id="Waarde_Lijst_4" waarde="" option_id="5"></span></p>


<form action="#">
  <div>
    <label for="input_2">Kleur</label>
    <div>
      <select name="color_id" id="input_2" class="form-control" onchange="vul_waarde()" onfocus="vul_waarde()">
        <option value="" selected="selected">--- does not matter ---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="input_3">Breedte</label>
    <div>
      <select name="breedte_id" id="input_3" class="form-control" onchange="vul_waarde()" onfocus="vul_waarde()">
        <option value="" selected="selected">--- does not matter ---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="input_4">Lengte</label>
    <div>
      <select name="lengte_id" id="input_4" class="form-control" onchange="vul_waarde()" onfocus="vul_waarde()">
        <option value="" selected="selected">--- does not matter ---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="input_5">Gesp</label>
    <div>
      <select name="gesp_id" id="input_5" class="form-control" onchange="vul_waarde()" onfocus="vul_waarde()">
        <option value="" selected="selected">--- does not matter ---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then remove all irrelevant code. Click the `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] substituting (assuming it works ok) the ajax call with a data example.
Also why use xmlhttprequest when you have jQUery loaded and can do $.ajax or $.get or $.post instead?

Comment: Lastly the jQuery in the first script is ANCIENT

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The code is already minimized, except that my 4 lists could be reduced to 3 lists, because I need 1 list to force the "onchange()", 1 list to proof my AJAX call is working (without the picture data) and my picturelist. I am NOT a jQuery nor javascript expert. I am just using hints from the internet, recent and or ancient if working and having (no recent security issues).

Comment: Any hint for a more recent working example showing pictures in a HTML-select list is welcome....

Comment: It is impossible for me to wade through your code to figure out what you are trying to do. Why do you post the first script? I made snippets out of both to have some formatting. I had to remove a loose `}` in the stylesheet.

What is the actual problem? You are mixing DOM and jquery, but what are the errors if any? Console errors, server errors?

Comment: @mplugjan Thanks for your effort. I am trying to have a user selection list with pictures. The first script is showing this. Now I am updating the list on-the-fly using the AJAX-part. This is working as expected, except the dynamically updated list contains the data, but visually the list does not show the elements. I can post a screen dump if that clarifies my problem. There are no console errors anywhere: nor PHP, nor Javascript / HTML. The result of the AJAX-call is exactly what is shown in the first script (containing data-class etc.)

Comment: @mplugjan and others: The images are not found off course by the first script due to the fact that they are relative URLs.

Comment: I understand the images are not there, easily found on the web to link directly https://webapitests2019.ctawave.org/images/ - but I need to have the seconds script cut down to ONE example and instead of the ajax, assuming it delivers an object, SHOW the object here: `function refresh_keuzelijst1(p1, w1, w2, w3, w4) {

      document.getElementById("input_2").innerHTML = responseText;
};` where responseText is the content of the first call

Comment: I think I may have found the reason: the script appears to create a new element: id="input_2-button". I noticed this viewing the HTML-source of the selected page-section (i.e. CTRL-A selected all, which differs from VIEW PAGE SOURCE in this case !) in the Firefox developpers tool. This tools shows my own element id="input-2" with the data retrieved via the AJAX-call. So my own element is not visible anymore. My "label" for input_2 is changed into a label for "input_2-button" as well.

Comment: Beside this a list is created with id="input_2-menu". I will try to fix it from here myself.

Comment: Goed zo! .......